# How to add more fields to the return response in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add more fields to the `Response` in the django rest framework to send to react frontend.

This works fine

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_status(request, task_id):
    task = current_app.AsyncResult(task_id)

    response_data = ImageSerializer(Image.objects.get(pk=task.get()))

    return Response(response_data.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

How can I add the `json context` below to the Response also?

```
#How can I add the following to my response too
context = {'task_status': task.status, 'task_id': task.id}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the extra data with:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_status(request, task_id):
    task = current_app.AsyncResult(task_id)

    response_data = ImageSerializer(Image.objects.get(pk=task.get()))
    context = {'task_status': task.status, 'task_id': task.id}

    return Response({**context, **response_data.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: this `**context` works like the `...context` in js?

Comment: @JoãoMazagão: yes, it constructs a new dictionary with the key-value pairs of the `context`, and the key-value pairs of the `response_data.data`. It thus "joins" the two together in a new dictionary.